# How to get submit button to update function in r-shiny

Tags: r, function, shiny, reactive-programming

### Goal:

My goal is to plot 3 graphs in shiny. I have a function that modifies the path of one of the graphs by the specified parameters. I'm interested in mapping the function to r-shiny sliders but have been unable to implement this functionality. Whenever I adjust the sliders - the function does not change. How do I map the submit button to the function?

### My Function:

```
Stress_Path <- function(delta, term) {                     # Stress Path function will modify the cumulative base vector by 'delta' for 'term' quarters

  stress_index <- c()                                      # Initialize a stress_index vector that will be populated within the Stress_Path function. 

  stress_index <- HPF$index_value + delta*(HPF$counter <= term)     # Use boolean algebra to simplify the code and avoid if else statements. 

  HPF$StressC <<- stress_index                              # Global scoping so that HPF data.frame is updated outside of function. 

  stress_indexplus <- c(stress_index[2:18370], NA)

  StressQoQ <- (stress_indexplus / stress_index) - 1
  StressQoQ <- c(NA, StressQoQ[1:18369])
  StressQoQ <- ifelse(HPF$index ==0, 0, StressQoQ)         # Global scoping so that StressQoQ is updated outside of function. 
  HPF$StressQoQ <<- StressQoQ                              # Global scoping so that HPF data.frame is updated outside of function. 


  return(HPF)
}
```

### What I Want in Shiny:

```
library(shiny)

#Define UI for dataset
ui <- fluidPage(

  #App title ----
  titlePanel("Home Price Forecasting under Stress Scenarios"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      #Input: Stress Path Function Parameters ----

      #Input: Numeric entry for region to plot ----
      numericInput(inputId = "region",
                   label = "Enter Region Number:",
                   value = "1", 
                   min = 1, 
                   max = 110), 

      sliderInput(inputId = "delta",
                  label = "Adjust Stress Path",
                  min = -75,
                  max = 75, 
                  step = 0.5),

      sliderInput(inputId = "terms",
                  label = "Number of Quarters to Adjust", 
                  min = 0, 
                  max = 166, 
                  step = 1),

      submitButton(text = "Apply Changes")



    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "ThYrC"),
              plotOutput(outputId = "FiYrC"), 
              plotOutput(outputId = "FoYrQtr")
    )

  )
)


#Define server logic to summarize and view selected dataset ----
server <- function(input, output){

  reactive({Stress_Path(input$delta/100, input$terms)})

  output$ThYrC <- renderPlot(plot_30cumulative(input$region))
  output$FiYrC <-  renderPlot(plot_5cumulative(input$region))
  output$FoYrQtr<- renderPlot(plot_4quarterly(input$region))


  }                   

# Run the application ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

### Problem:

I'm failing to "update" the graphs after adjusting the sliders. I'm curious how to implement the submit button. Any insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

> observeEvent()

instead of reactive():

```
observeEvent(list(input$region, input$delta, input$terms), {
    Stress_Path(input$delta/100, input$terms)
    output$ThYrC <- renderPlot(plot_30cumulative(input$region))
    output$FiYrC <-  renderPlot(plot_5cumulative(input$region))
    output$FoYrQtr<- renderPlot(plot_4quarterly(input$region))
    #Do any other stuff that you need after pressing submit button
})
```

I use one observeEvent to all inputs for example ofcourse.